# How to correct the shape of the separator in modeline, when using spaceline?

Tags: emacs, modeline

My mode-line has problems when changing the shape of the separator, when using the [spaceline](https://github.com/TheBB/spaceline) package which has powerline as a dependency. It applies the change of shape of the separator but the colours are not right. Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

I am using vanilla emacs in GUI mode version 25.

Comment: Too broad. You are asking about at least 3 different mode-line packages. Pick one. And the answer will probably be to look at the doc for that package. Or contact the package maintainer if the answer is not obvious from the package doc and code.

Comment: I am saying that the problem persists regardless of the package, so maybe there is a mode-line configuration which is affecting it when applying the packages. Just my thought, but I am looking into what you mentioned.

Comment: There is no mode-line separator in the default case. So clearly this is about one or more of the packages you are using. Narrow the question, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out to be a spaceline specific problem. I fixed it by adding the following settings.

```
(setq powerline-height 20)
(setq powerline-raw " ")
(setq ns-use-srgb-colorspace nil)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to be more specific and better reflect the answer.